# Why is the number of divisors of an integer $n$ equal to the number of factors in the factorization of the polynomial $x^n - 1$ over the integers?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, factoring

Sloane's OEIS A000005 gives the number of divisors of the integer n.  A comment (by a very reputable contributor) in this sequence claims that this is also the number of factors in the factorization of the polynomial $x^n-1$ over the integers.
For example a(6) = 4 because there are 4 divisors of the integer 6 and (apparently) because there are 4 factors in the factorization of $x^6 - 1=  
(-1 + x) (1 + x) (1 - x + x^2) (1 + x + x^2)$.

Is there an easy explanation for this?  How can I count the number of factors in the factorization of $x^n - 1$?  Is there an algorithm to produce these factors? 
I read an article on-line that gave a method to produce all the factors of x^n - 1 with no rational roots ( that is 1 and -1 are not roots) but this is not the same as the  irreducible factors that are being counted in this sequence.

Comment: How much Galois Theory do you know? Specifically, what do you know about Cyclotomic fields?

Comment: I will be starting a course in Field Theory in January.  Right now I don't even know how to spell cyclotomic fields.  lol

Comment: [$X^n-1=\prod_{d\mid n}\Phi_d(X)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial)

Comment: @user26857  Yes thank you.  I did some reading about the nth cyclotomic polynomials.  I do not understand the proof that they are irreducible over the integers but, assuming this,  then your equation above fully answers my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to construct a bijection between divisors $d$ of $n$ and irreducible factors $F$ of $X^n-1$.

Given a divisor $d$, let $F$ be the $d$-th cyclotomic polynomial (the minimal polynomial of a primitive $d$-th root of unity). Then $F$ is irreducible, and $F \mid X^d - 1 \mid X^n - 1$.

Given an irreducible factor $F$ of $X^n-1$, let $d$ be minimal such that $F \mid X^d - 1$. Then $F \mid \gcd(X^d-1,X^n-1)=X^{\gcd(d,n)}-1$, which implies $d \leq \gcd(d,n)$ hence $d \mid n$.

It now remains to show that these two maps (of which we have shown that they are well-defined) are inverses of each other.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: If $n = ab$, then $x^n -1 = (x^a)^b -1^b$. Now, factorize this as a difference of $b$-th powers and find a bijection between factorizations and divisors.

Comment: (x^a)^b - 1 = (x^a - 1)*( (x^a)^(b-1) + (x^a)^(b-2) + ... + (x^a) + 1.  How does this lead to a bijection?